# DolphinDB Beta release: maximum cache size for TSDB index and related functions?

Tags: dolphindb

The DolphinDB beta release (200) allows specifying *sortColumns* for tables created with the TSDB engine. The system then sorts the data in each chunk based on the specified *sortColumn* to create index. What's the default maximum cache size for the index? How to check the usage?

Answer (score 0):

The default maximum memory size for TSDB is 5% of the total memory allocated to DolphinDB (specified by configuration parameter maxMemSize), and it must not be less than 0.1GB.

You can also specify a value through the configuration parameter TSDBLevelFileIndexCacheSize. The unit is GB.

Use the this statement to check the memory occupied by the TSDB index:

```
select capacity\1024\1024\1024 as capacityGB, round(usage\1024\1024\1024,2) as usageGB from pnodeRun(getLevelFileIndexCacheStats)
```